# I'm using serverless application method and Js Report feature not running on AWS Lambda. That throws error like mentioned below

Tags: aws-lambda, jsreport

As I have used the serverless structure for my Node application and wanted to implement the jsreport 2.10.1 to download my reports oriented things.

I have configured all regarding the jsreport configurations

```
const jsreport = require("jsreport-core")({
  rootDirectory: __dirname,
});
jsreport.use(require("jsreport-handlebars")());
jsreport.use(require("jsreport-chrome-pdf")());
 jsreport.use(require("jsreport-html-to-xlsx")());
 jsreport.use(
   require("jsreport-assets")({
     searchOnDiskIfNotFoundInStore: true,
     allowedFiles: "**/*.*",
   })
 );
jsreport.init();

export default class DownloadService {
  constructor() {
    // Empty Constructor
  }

  async generateFile(module: String, datas: any, template: any) {
    try {
      return jsreport
        .render({
          template: template,
          data: datas,
        })
        .then((resp: Record<string, unknown>) => {
          const content = { content: resp.content } as Record<string, unknown>;
          content.reportname =
            (module ? module : "download") +
            (template.recipe == "chrome-pdf" ? ".pdf" : ".XLSX");
          return {
            success: true,
            message: "Template and data binded successfully",
            data: content,
          };
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return {
            success: false,
            message: error.message,
          };
        });
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject({
        success: false,
        message: `internal error is ${err}`,
        code: 500,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I have used  layers to pack all dependencies and I have mentioned here:

```
{
  "name": "testlambda",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "^8.10.0",
    "pg-native": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "jsreport-assets": "^1.7.0",
    "jsreport-chrome-pdf": "^1.10.0",
    "jsreport-core": "^2.10.1",
    "jsreport-handlebars": "^2.1.0",
    "jsreport-html-to-xlsx": "^2.6.0",
    "jsreport-phantom-pdf": "^2.6.1",
    "should": "^13.2.3",
    "emitter": "^0.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aws-lambda": "^1.0.7"
  }
}
```

When I call one endpoint `invoice-generate`, I just implement my logic and call this generateFile object and that works properly in my local machine.

When I deployed same on AWS lambda using serverless.js file there apps gets crash and throws like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d0vN.jpg)

I found this in my cloud watcher.

I'm not sure what I missed and what is the root cause of this.

Folks please provide me a any insights to fix this and make this run successfully on my Lambda function.

Below is the my serverless.js lambda function configurations.

```
serverHandler:
    handler: dist/index.server
    timeout: 600
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: ANY
          cors:
            origin: "*"
            headers: ${self:custom.allowed-headers}
            allowCredentials: true
   
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors:
            origin: "*"
            headers: ${self:custom.allowed-headers}
            allowCredentials: true
          authorizer: ${self:custom.authorizer.cognito_authorizer}

    iamRoleStatementsName: "EVCognitoAdminRole${opt:stage}"
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - "cognito-idp:AdminUserGlobalSignOut"
          - "cognito-idp:AddCustomAttributes"
          - "cognito-idp:AdminCreateUser"
          - "cognito-idp:AdminSetUserPassword"
          - "cognito-idp:AdminSetUserSettings"
          - "cognito-idp:AdminAddUserToGroup"
          - "cognito-idp:GetGroup"
          - "cognito-idp:AdminGetUser"
          - "cognito-idp:AdminConfirmSignUp"
          - "cognito-idp:AdminEnableUser"
          - "cognito-idp:AdminListUserAuthEvents"
          - "cognito-idp:UpdateGroup"
          - "cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth"
          - "cognito-idp:AdminDisableUser"
          - "cognito-idp:AdminRemoveUserFromGroup"
          - "cognito-idp:AdminResetUserPassword"
          - "cognito-idp:AdminUpdateUserAttributes"
        Resource:
          - !GetAtt cognitoUserPool.Arn

      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - "sns:SetSMSAttributes"
          - "sns:Publish"
        Resource: "*"

      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - "s3:GetObject"
          - "s3:PutObject"
          - "s3:PutObjectAcl"
          - "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
          - "s3:DeleteObject"
        Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.publicBucketName}"
```

I have tried all the debugging inside the nodemodules also and i cant find the root cause or solution for this. i wish to know about this solution

Comment: Without more detail it's hard for anyone to troubleshoot. If you can check that transpiled JS bundle for the code mentioned in the stack trace, that would be useful. [This search may be helpful to you](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Ajsreport++language%3AJavaScript+%2F%28%3F-i%29%5C.filename%2F&type=code) (my guess it is it has something to do with accessing `module.parent.filename` in jsreport).